# Condition for this case

Tags: c#

Several types of strings can come:

1. "SW"
2. "SW3"
3. "SW1W"
4. or "SW1W 5" up to "SW1W 5NY"

I can't build the logic correctly in such a way that if there is a "space" character in the string and there is the following symbol (as I showed in version 4) - save(add to the database) this string without a space at the end.
And in the opposite case => (if there is no space and there is not a single character after), then add a "space" at the end of the line.

I need to then drive it to the initiator of the object:

```
Postcode = dal.Country == "GB" 
    && dal.Point1PostCode.Length < 4
       ? string.Concat(dal.PostCode, SpaceSymbol) 
       : dal.PostCode,
```

Perhaps there is another and easier option. This is mine, which I got =(

Comment: In order to remove spaces at the end of the string, you may use the [TrimEnd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trimend?view=net-6.0) method. If you need to remove spaces somewhere inside the string - simply replace all occurrences of the space character with the empty string. In order to add spaces to the end, you can use simple string concatenation

Comment: Your examples are a good start, but can you be more precise about the expected _format_ of your inputs, what exact section of that format you wish to capture, and how you determine what action to take?

Comment: @gunr2171 In short, it's the britainian postcode. it can have in the first part (before spacing) 2, 3 or 4 character then there are always 3 characters(i dont count them).

in project i had logic like matching, for instance: when google api return me full postcode like "SW1W 5NY" and i have in db SW1 - it's match. BUT, this is a large distance between SW1 and SW1W.

so i decided to write in database first part with the "space" symbol. To get away from this problem.

now i want to write in db like i mentioned it in head of topic

Comment: i have a file uploader, where i specify which postcode i can handle for instance => BS3. System should look at this BS3, if there are not some spaces and characters it have to write into db "BS3 " if there(in file upload) is "BS3 4" it has to save in db just "BS3 4"

Comment: So the question is "Given a partial or complete UK Postcode string, how do I extract the [District](https://ideal-postcodes.co.uk/guides/uk-postcode-format) value?"

Comment: @gunr2171 hmm... yes, shortly - district.

Comment: @gunr2171 hmm... yes, shortly - district. i would say more the "Outward Code"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the definition of a UK Postcode from [ideal-postcodes.co.uk](https://ideal-postcodes.co.uk/guides/uk-postcode-format):

[image: https://img.ideal-postcodes.co.uk/uk-postcode-components.gif]

---

If you're looking for the "outcode", simply split by a space and take the first element.

```
var input = "SW1W 5NY";
var outcode = input.Split(' ')[0];
// outcode is "SW1W"
```

This even works with incomplete entries:

```
SW -> SW
SW3 -> SW3
SW1W -> SW1W
SW1W 5 -> SW1W
```

[Online example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Gl5II5)

---

If you're looking for the "district" then you need to be a bit more crafty about the symbols you're reading.

- The "area" is the *continuous* letters at the start of the string.
- The "district" is the "area" plus the *continuous* digits directly after the area.

There's also the note "the district value can be two to four symbols long", but that doesn't really matter to us, as we're not doing validation.

An easy regex can accomplish this. However it gets a bit more complicated because you can pass in an *incomplete* postcode.

```
var input = "SW1W 5NY";
var pattern = Regex(@"^([A-Z]{1,4}\d{0,4})");
var match = pattern.Match(input);
// match.Groups[1].Value is "SW1"
```

[Online example for all inputs](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NJErQT)

To explain the regex pattern:

- `^` - make sure you start matching at the start of the string
- `(` - start capturing into group 1
- `[A-Z]{1,4}` - look for uppercase letters 1 to 4 times
- `\d{0,4}` - look for digits 0 to 4 times. The lower bound is 0 to account for incomplete postcode inputs.
- `)` - stop capturing into group 1